# Bootstrap layout login page problem with flex containers and displaying background image

Tags: html, css

For some time I'm struggling with some really painful problems.

I'm trying to create a login page with a simple layout:

**On screens over 800px width:**

- Two columns
- On the left side, I want to show a logo, login form, text box, and button. No Background image.
- On the right side, I want to show a div with a background image.

**On screens less than or equal to 800px with:**

- A single column with the logo, login form, text box, and button.
- The background image that is shown in the right column on large screens should be displayed as the background image of this single column on small screens.

Html file

```
<div class="flex-container">
<div class="col-lg-4 index-top">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col log-in">
            <div class="col no-padding">
                <h1>
                    <img src="/img/AnonimowySygnalista.svg" alt="logo Anonimowy Sygnalista" class="logo-login" />
                    <span class="sr-only hidden">Anonimowy sygnalista</span>
                </h1>
                <form action="">
                    <label for="">UserName</label>
                    <input type="" id="" name="" placeholder="Wpisz otrzymany login" class="input"></input>
                    <input type="submit" value="Zaloguj" class="btn-primary"></input>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-8 col background-img">
</div>
```

CSS file

```
.container {
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
input, textarea {
    display: block;
}
.right {
    float: right;
}
.left {
    float: left;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
label {
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-bottom: .75rem;
}
.btn-primary {
    background-color: #1F7AAB;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border-color: #1F7AAB;
    padding: .5rem 1.5rem;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: none;
    color: #fff;
}
.background-img {
    background-image: url('../img/pexels-vlada-karpovich-4050312.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    margin-top: -1.25rem;
}
.input {
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
    max-height: 5rem;
    padding: .5rem .5rem .5rem .75rem;
    border: 1px solid #767676;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 4px;
    width: 100%;
}
.log-in h1 {
    margin: 3rem 0;
}
.index-top {
    z-index: 999;
}
@media (min-width: 801px) {
    .container {
        width: 100% !important;
    }
    .flex-container {
        padding-right: 80px;
        flex-direction: row;
    }
    .index-top {
        margin: 0 80px;
    }
```

Comment: The problem that I have right now: how to set height to 100% of the page? Height: 100%, Min-height: 100% doesn't work.
In mobile now my div with background has 0px height and on desktop (over 800px width) has the same height as left column content. Both shoul be for 100% of the page

Answer (score 0):

to stack elements on top of each other use `position : absolute`

adding it to `.background-img` inside @media should produce the effect, also you'll need the `z-index` css property to manage which element is behind which

Comment: The problem that I have: how to set height to 100% of the page? Height: 100%, Min-height: 100% doesn't work.
In mobile now my div with background has 0px height and on desktop (over 800px width) has the same height as left column content. Both shoul be for 100% of the page

Comment: `height: 100%` is 100% of the parent element, if you want the height to be 100% of the screen you should use `height: 100vh` which is `viewport height`

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you would like for the background image to show on the right on large screens & you would like for the background image to show behind the form on small screens.

A simple way to implement this would be to add a CSS class `.bg-sometimes` to the small (left side) column. We set this class to display a background image. Then, within our `@media (min-width: 801px)`, we set `background-image: none;` so that the image does not display on large screens.

The code below demonstrates this implementation nicely.

```css
 .container {
        display: block;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .flex-container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    input, textarea {
        display: block;
    }
    .right {
        float: right;
    }
    .left {
        float: left;
    }
    .clear {
        clear: both;
    }
    label {
        font-weight: 700;
        margin-bottom: .75rem;
    }
    .btn-primary {
        background-color: #1F7AAB;
        border-radius: 4px;
        border-color: #1F7AAB;
        padding: .5rem 1.5rem;
        width: 100%;
        box-shadow: none;
        color: #fff;
    }
    .background-img {
        background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/235986/pexels-photo-235986.jpeg');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
        background-size: cover;
        margin-top: -1.25rem;
    }
    .input {
        margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
        max-height: 5rem;
        padding: .5rem .5rem .5rem .75rem;
        border: 1px solid #767676;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border-radius: 4px;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .log-in h1 {
        margin: 3rem 0;
    }
    .index-top {
        z-index: 999;
    }

    .bg-sometimes {
        background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/235986/pexels-photo-235986.jpeg');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
        background-size: cover;
        margin-top: -1.25rem;
    }

    @media (min-width: 801px) {
        .container {
            width: 100% !important;
        }
        .flex-container {
            padding-right: 80px;
            flex-direction: row;
        }
        .index-top {
            margin: 0 80px;
        }
        .bg-sometimes {
            background-image: none;
        }
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="bg-sometimes col-lg-4 index-top">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col log-in">
                <div class="col no-padding">
                    <h1>
                        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4f/SVG_Logo.svg"
                             alt="logo Anonimowy Sygnalista" class="logo-login"/>
                        <span class="sr-only hidden">Anonimowy sygnalista</span>
                    </h1>
                    <form action="">
                        <label for="">UserName</label>
                        <input type="" id="" name="" placeholder="Wpisz otrzymany login" class="input"></input>
                        <input type="submit" value="Zaloguj" class="btn-primary"></input>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8 col background-img">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank You for such detaild answer

The problem that I have: how to set height to 100% of the page? Height: 100%, Min-height: 100% doesn't work.
In mobile now my div with background has 0px height and on desktop (over 800px width) has the same height as left column content. Both shoul be for 100% of the page